# Python running shell script with subprocess returns 'fuse: device not found'

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, fuse, s3fs

I'm trying to mount an S3 bucket with s3fs so I can have access to the files in the bucket from a JupyterLab server. When I mount it directly from the terminal, by running `s3fs <bucket_name>:/<bucket_folder> /home/<username>/s3-bucket -o umask=022 -o allow_other` it works properly and mounts the S3 folder on the filesystem.

However, I need to do this when a user logs in to JupyterHub, which creates a user in the server, and I have to mount the S3 bucket for that specific user. For that reason, I am trying to mount the bucket from a python script that runs every time a user logs in.
I run the same command from python, using the `subprocess` module:

```
bash_command = f"s3fs <bucket-name>:/<bucket-folder> /home/{system_username}/s3-bucket -o umask=022 -o allow_other".split()
result = subprocess.run(bash_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

It throws the following error:

`CompletedProcess(args=['s3fs', '<bucket-name>:/<bucket-folder>', '/home/<username>/s3-bucket', '-o', 'umask=022', '-o', 'allow_other'], returncode=1, stdout='', stderr="fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first\n")`

Comment: The context -- how your Python program is started, by which process, in which security context -- is critical to this. The problem almost certainly has nothing at all to do with the Python itself and everything to do with the context in which that Python is invoked (which can mean the set of capabilities the script is run with, or SELinux attributes by the parent executable, or so forth).

Comment: BTW, splitting a string is _far_ worse practice than just passing a list in the first place; it breaks with usernames that have spaces in them, f/e. Much better to use `bash_command = [ 's3fs', f'{bucket_name}:/{bucket_folder}', f'/home/{system_username}/s3-bucket', '-o', 'umask=022', '-o', 'allow_other']`.

Comment: ...note that folks building shared infrastructure generally have very good reasons to lock it down and _not_ allow filesystem namespace changes, userspace filesystems, &c to be accessed.